# FileIterator.next() not working

Tags: google-apps-script

07/19/2017 The `FileIterator.next()` method has ceased to work.

> Message: The following object can not be obtained: iterator has reached the end of the set.

Search for a file created before 07/19/2017 is correct.

All scripts worked correctly for a long time until 07/19/2017, perhaps that has changed in the methods of GAS.

Where can I go for help?

Code sample

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('FileName').next().getId();
```

and

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Filename');  
if (files.hasNext()) {

    SpreadsheetApp.openById(files.next().getId()).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(), Family, Name]);  
}
```

and

```
var firstLevelFolderName = "MyFolderName";
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(firstLevelFolderName);
var firstLevelFolder = (folders.hasNext()) ? folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(firstLevelFolderName);
```

Comment: If this is truly a "bug" then you can submit an "issue."  [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open)

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me. It's a function I have in my utilities library.

```
function loadFile(filename,folderID)
{
  var filename = (typeof(filename) !== 'undefined')? filename : DefaultFileName;
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : DataFolderID;
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  var s = '';
  while(file.hasNext())
  {
    var fi = file.next();
    var target = fi.getName();
    if(target == filename)
    {
      s = fi.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```